# Error setting up thrift modules for python

Tags: python, thrift

I'm trying to set up [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) in order to incorporate with [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/), so when I ran the

```
setup.py
```

it out puts this message in command line

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'thrift.protocol.fastbinary' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Pytho
n26\PC -c src/protocol/fastbinary.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\protocol
\fastbinary.o
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:24:24: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:85:4: #error "Cannot determine endianness"
src/protocol/fastbinary.c: In function `writeI16':
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:295: warning: implicit declaration of function `htons'

src/protocol/fastbinary.c: In function `writeI32':
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:300: warning: implicit declaration of function `htonl'

src/protocol/fastbinary.c: In function `readI16':
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:688: warning: implicit declaration of function `ntohs'

src/protocol/fastbinary.c: In function `readI32':
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:696: warning: implicit declaration of function `ntohl'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Need some helping on this issue.I have already install the MigW32

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like the compiler is missing some of the includes it needs (e.g. "netinet/in.h")... a common issue when trying to compile add-ins and modules and such in Windows. You'll probably need to ensure that GCC can find all the files in "C:\Python26\include" as well as any other libraries needed for Thrift and Cassandra...

Comment: Still getting the same errors, I followed the methods described here http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/issues/detail?id=104 that's how I get so far.Now couldn't figure this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only succeeded in installing Thrift with MSVC.

- Install MSVC
- Get Thrift
- Apply thrift-252-python-msvc-1.diff patch (google it)

The fastbinary.c will be patched, but setup.py patch will fail, update manually from hints at setup.py.rej, here's a (seemingly) correct copy:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import sys

libraries = []

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    libraries.append('ws2_32')

fastbinarymod = Extension('thrift.protocol.fastbinary',
                          sources = ['src/protocol/fastbinary.c'],
                          libraries = libraries, 
        )

setup(name = 'Thrift',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'Thrift Python Libraries',
      author = 'Thrift Developers',
      author_email = 'thrift-dev@incubator.apache.org',
      url = 'http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/',
      license = 'Apache License 2.0',
      packages = [
        'thrift',
        'thrift.protocol',
        'thrift.transport',
        'thrift.server',
      ],
      package_dir = {'thrift' : 'src'},
      ext_modules = [fastbinarymod],
      )
```

Endianness test will fail, modify fastbinary.c (around line 68):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #define __BYTE_ORDER __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#endif
```

After that run `python setup.py install`, hopefully, you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of source file tweaking it is possible to install it with MINGW on Windows. I'm using thrift 0.9.1 and Python 27

The steps I followed were:

1. If you are using Python 2.7, follow the normal setup steps and workarounds for minGW. In particular you may need to open the file C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py, and modify the class Mingw32CCompiler to remove all references to the -mno-cygwin option. This option is deprecated and will cause the compiler to halt with an error if it is left in.
2. Open fastbinary.c and add the following include statement,

> `#include <stdbool.h>,`

this includes definitions for true / false which will otherwise cause the compile to fail. (I assume they're included by default on MSVC?)

3) Modify the setup.py file to tell the linker to link to ws2_32.lib. This is done using a pragma comment on MSVC, but gcc doesn't support this option. So your ext_modules should look like :

```
ext_modules = [
                 Extension('thrift.protocol.fastbinary',
                       sources = ['src/protocol/fastbinary.c'],
                       libraries=['ws2_32'],
                    include_dirs = include_dirs,
                )
            ],
```

4) Build as normal using the setup.py

On my setup, I didn't get much of a speed improvement when using the C extension rather than pure python (about a 5% difference), so the effort to do this might not be justified except in extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

Install python-dev

You can run:
sudo apt-get install python-dev

Comment: I guess this was down-voted by someone because it doesn't directly address the question, but I am up-voting it because it fixed my issue... installing via `pip install pycassa` gives an error about `building 'thrift.protocol.fastbinary' extension` and presumably therefore doesn't install the fast C extension... your answer fixed this for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to execute the following command:

```
pip3 install thriftpy2
```